# Processing.org user input code error?

Tags: joptionpane

Could you help me find the error in my code.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

String mortgagetype;

mortgagetype = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What type of mortgage do you desire? (open or closed, only)"); 

if (mortgagetype == "open" || mortgagetype == "closed") {
 print("hello"); 
}
```

I want the program to print hello if the user inputs open or closed. However it doesn't and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Please add the error that you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `mortgagetype == "something"` in the if statement, use `mortgagetype.equals("something")`.

Comment: This is a valid answer. Comparing string with `==` checks if the two strings are the *same instance*. While `.equals()` method checks if the two string have *same content*.